# How to Import Production Data From Cloud Firestore to the Local Emulator?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to prototype my app in local firebase emulator suite.

I already have some data from production in my firestore database that I want to import to my emulator and I am following the guide below:

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-import-production-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-the-local-emulator-e82ae1c6ed8

However I am getting the error when trying to do this step:

**3. Export your production data to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, providing a name of your choice:**

`gcloud firestore export gs://your-project-name.appspot.com/your-choosen-folder-name`

my code:

`gcloud firestore export gs://myapp-proto.appspot.com/myapp-proto-data`

I get the following error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.firestore.export) NOT_FOUND: Google Cloud Storage file does not exist:`

How can file not exist if I am trying to create it by importing it? what am I doing wrong? is there another way for me to transfer data?

Comment: I don't know the answer, BUT - WHEN do you get the error?  On the export, or on the attempted import into the emulator, or downloading the exported file to local storage...?

Answer (score 0):

the correct command is `gcloud firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]`

so, in your case `gcloud firestore export gs://myapp-proto.appspot.com/myapp-proto-data`

does myapp-proto.appspot.com/myapp-proto-data  is the bucket you have created already? if not make sure the buckted URI is correct and bucket do exist before running this command.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#gcloud

Comment: This answer doesn't look correct because the import works only back to production Firebase. You're not able to import it to Firebase Emulator in this way. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled to import from one Firebase project's bucket to another. However, downloading it straight from one bucket through google CLI then uploading it onto the other bucket worked.

When you try to download some folder, it will prompt you with the command to be used in google CLI.

It'll be something like

```
$ gsutil -m cp -r \
  "gs://{bucket-name}/{folder-name}" \
  .
```

-> replace {xxxx} by your respective asset name.